# java - design patterns - inheritance with static variables

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a Person class that extends my Record class and i'd like to define the database table name, columns, and column types as static variables in the Person class. I'd like to do something like the following but i can't because i can't modify objects when not in a method(i think? java noob here).

```
class Person extends Record{
    protected static final String dbTable = "people";
    protected static LinkedHashMap<String, String> dbColumns = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    dbColumns.put("id","integer");
    dbColumns.put("name", "text");
}
```

I could do the following but it looks messy and not very readable especially if my table has several columns

```
class Person extends Record{
    protected static final String dbTable = "people";
    protected static final String[] dbColumns= {"id","name"};
    protected static final String[] dbColumnTypes= {"integer","text"};

}
```

I don't want to define these in the constructor because I want a static method in the parent class(Record) that i can do something like the following to get a list of Person records

```
List<Person> people = Person.getAll();
```

My initial thought was to create the following abstract methods in my Record class and their implementation in the Person class would return the appropriate static variables.

```
public abstract String getTableName();
public abstract String[] getColumnNames();
public abstract String[] getColumnTypes();
```

BUT i can't do that because my static method, getAll(), can't reference non-static methods. How do i let my static method, getAll(), aware that those static variables exist in an extended class and can use them?

I'm know there's a correct way to go about doing this, i just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do what you're doing with the abstract methods, and then all you need to do is change your static getAll() to be something like getAll(Record record) and just have it call those methods.

You're on the right track. I would avoid relying on static things for anything outside of the class itself in favor of exposing instance methods that may themselves call private or protected static fields, personally.

Comment: so do something like Record.getAllColumnsFor(new Person())? which would create an empty object just to get those static variables?

Comment: I wonder if I misunderstood your question. What is getAll supposed to do? I thought it was getting column names that you will be using to query the database. If that is the case then my edit might be better. But it looks like you might be using a static getAll to query your database and return a list of Persons. If that is the case I would say, Dont do that. Use an object whose job it is to give you data instead of a static thing to give you that kind of data.

Comment: Other than changing getAll to be a member of an instance class (and definitely not part of person!) I think that solution is still sound.

Comment: Yes, the goal of getAll() would be to return a list of Person objects. I think your suggestion of a separate object to return the objects is the way to go here. I just can't figure out in my head how the new 'RecordFinder' object would reference those static variables without creating an empty object to use its abstract methods...

Comment: Using a throwaway object like that isn't unheard of. Look at List<T>'s method, toArray which accepts an array as an argument to tell it what type of array. Many many many people pass a new array of the desired type of length zero. So its not unprecedented and I think you'll find it to be a good way to generalize your program. What if you need all records of type Dog for example? Then just implement those get column methods on dog and it will still return a result set.

Comment: ok sweet. that makes me feel better. I come from a PHP background so the whole memory management concepts are way more important in Java and i'm still learning what's acceptable and what isn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can do static initializer blocks in a class. They look like this:

```
static
{
    dbColumns.put("id","integer");
    dbColumns.put("name", "text");
}
```

Static initializer blocks run once before the class is used - anywhere between the program starting up and the class being loaded.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean when it runs is indeterminate?

Comment: @Koray Tugay I may be thinking of the C/C++ equivalent.

Comment: @Koray Tugay I think this is a little more accurate.

Comment: It will run sometime after the class loader loads it but always BEFORE the class's static methods and fields are accessed which is the important part.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using enums. You can also use an interface to provide abstraction between various Db-based classes.

```
interface DbColumn{
  String getName();
  String getType();
}

enum PersonDbColumns implements DbColumn {
  ID("integer"),
  NAME("text");

  PersonDbColumns(String type) {
    this.type=type;
  }

  private String type;

  String getName() {
    return this.toString();
  }

  String getType() {
    return type;
  } 

}
```

You can add more fields to each column. You gain the advantage of compile-time error if you do not fill all elements of the enum, provided you use the constructor for initialization. You have `valuOf()` and `Class.getEnumConstants()` to get the enum from string or to get all columns from given table.

Comment: oh man. enums scare me. I've yet to wrap my head completely around them. Could you write some dummy code showing the use of this enum in another class, like my Person class? I can't visualize how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

The best practics for this is to Have Utility class that contains all these stuff methods and variabls as static. The Utility class usually has no construction. you could also use static block

```
  static {
   initialize your static variables here
  }
```

Comment: Utility classes are not 'the way you're meant to write Java', especially when thinking about things that are objects in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Your class Record contains `static final` variables. There is no need to use a getter method to fetch the value of your ststic variables. As far as I can understand you are planning to call a db query inside getAll() method. you should simply access the static variables using `Classname.variable_name`

```
Record.dbTable;
Record.dbColumns;
Record.dbColumnTypes;
```

Comment: that wouldn't work because I plan on having several difference classes that extend Record. Like a Company class which would have a different table and columns.